# Google Cloud Functions - How to import a Python package (via PIP) from a GCP Repository in another project?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, package, gcloud

I need to have private Python packages in GCP usable in multiple projects. I haven't tried the Artifact Registry since that's still in alpha, so right now I've been trying with simple repositories, but I'm open to alternatives.

I have a Python package source code in a GCP Repository in Project A, and I have a cloud function in a repository also in Project A. In this cloud function I import the mentioned package by adding `git+https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-a/r/my-python package` in my `requirements.txt` file.

If I deploy this cloud function in Project A via `gcloud functions` in my terminal, specifying `--source=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/project-a/repos/my-cloud-function` and `--project=project-a`, it works fine, and the function can successfully import the elements from the package when I call it, but if I deploy this function in Project B instead, I get the following error:

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                                                                             
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
  Running command git clone -q https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-a/r/my-python-package /tmp/pip-req-build-f_bcp4y9
  remote: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
  remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo]
  remote: request_id: "abe4(...)"
  fatal: unable to access 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-a/r/my-python-package/': The requested URL returned error: 403
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-a/r/my-python-package /tmp/pip-req-build-f_bcp4y9 Check the logs for full command output.
```

This seems like a permissions issue. However, if I remove the package dependency from `requirements.txt`, it deploys fine, which means that Project B indeed has access to repos from Project A, so it seems like a issue inside Pip. However, Pip has no problems if I deploy to Project A, so I'm a little lost.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See the vendoring section in the docs. I'm using Golang (rather than Python) with private repos and vendoring worked for me. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#using_private_dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was hoping to leave vendoring as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Artifact Registry is GA](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/devops-sre/artifact-registry-is-ga) and no longer on Alpha/Beta since last year.

I replicated your issue. The error is indeed due to permissions, it didn't happened on the deployment when you remove the line on the `requirements.txt`, probably because the credentials had access to both projects.

In order to make the deployment correct you have to add the permissions on the repository to the service account that makes the deployment (which is the CF service account) that can be found on `Cloud Functions` - `(select your Cloud Function)` - `Details`, it should be something like `project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

Once you have located the service account add it to the Cloud Repository by clicking on `Settings` - `Permissions` and add it with at least the `Source Repository Reader` role

Comment: Artifact Registry is GA for Docker images, but it's still in alpha for Python, Maven and NPM packages at the moment.

Comment: I added the reader role to the service account on Project B, although I did it on the `IAM & Admin` screen since I couldn't manage to do it from `Cloud Repository`. However, I get the same error while trying to deploy. Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the `Source Repository Reader` role just means that the service account has access to the repos from that same project? I'm trying to deploy a function to Project B, but the dependency is on Project A.

Comment: Lets say your Cloud Repository is on project A, then the SA of Cloud Functions from Project B should be added in the `IAM & Admin` section on project A so it has permissions on Project A even if it's on Project B

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I tried adding my Project B service account into Project A with the `Source Repository Reader` role, but i got the same error, unfortunately. Probably I'm doing something wrong on my end, since I'm new to GCP. I'll still accept your answer, as it can be useful for someone else. Thanks for all the help.